# How to limit different concurrency number by service on Tonic?

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tonic

As we know **Tonic** uses the `Service` and `Layer` mechanism of **Tower** framework, if we want to add the concurrency limit on the service on the server side, we can do this:

```rust
let layer = tower::ServiceBuilder::new().
    .load_shed()
    .concurrency_limit(2)
    .into_inner();

Service::builder()
    .layer(layer)
    .add_service(greeter)
    .add_service(echo)
    .serve(addr)
    .await?;
```

The above code we have: the greeter and echo service maximum concurrency is 2, both for the connection of concurrent cap of a total of 4, exert the function of each layer service is the same, I understand it right?

Now what if I want to implement different concurrency limits for the `greeter` and `echo` services, say 3 for one and 2 for the other? I couldn't find a corresponding method in **Tonic**'s documentation or code.
However, for the **Tower** `Service` it is possible, I can wrap the two services separately, for example:

```rust
let greeter = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .load_shed()    
    .concurrency_limit(3)
    .service(greeter);

let echo = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .load_shed()    
    .concurrency_limit(2)
    .service(echo);

Server::builder()
    .add_service(greeter)
    .add_service(echo)
    .serve(addr)
    .await?;
```

But that won't work. Because `add_service()` method requires the participation of type must implement the `tonic::server::NamedService` trait.

I could implement this trait in a newtype, but it only defines a `const NAME` element.
I'm not very familiar with generic programming in Rust and haven't found a way to implement it yet.

May I ask if anyone understands this or has done similar functions? I need your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, the service you are looking for should ideally be generated while compiling.
You should have `build.rs`:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tonic_build::compile_protos("proto/service.proto")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

The protofile might look like:

```
package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
    // Sends a greeting
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
    string message = 1;
}
```

This would generate some code like this:

```rust
//---snip--
impl<T: Greeter> tonic::server::NamedService for GreeterServer<T> {
    const NAME: &'static str = "helloworld.Greeter";
}
```

You would still need to implement the greeter implementation:

```rust
// Implement the service skeleton for the "Greeter" service
// defined in the proto
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyGreeter {}

// Implement the service function(s) defined in the proto
// for the Greeter service (SayHello...)
#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Greeter for MyGreeter {
    async fn say_hello(
        &self,
        request: Request<HelloRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<HelloResponse>, Status> {
        println!("Received request from: {:?}", request);

        let response = greeter::HelloResponse {
            message: format!("Hello {}!", request.into_inner().name).into(),
        };

        Ok(Response::new(response))
    }
}
```

You would bring it all together with the server:

```rust
let greeter = MyGreeter::default();
Server::builder()
    .add_service(GreeterServer::new(greeter))
    .serve(addr)
    .await?;
```

With that working, you still face a problem where using different layers may change what you want.
You may want to create a wrapper type.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct GreetWrapper<Service>(Service);

impl<S: NamedService> NamedService for GreetWrapper<S> {
    const NAME: &'static str = S::NAME;
}

fn main() {
    let greeter = MyGreeter::default();
    let greeter = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
        .load_shed()
        .concurrency_limit(3)
        .service(GreeterServer::new(greeter));
    tonic::transport::Server::builder().add_service(GreetWrapper(greeter));
}
```

Here is an example that compiles:

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
tower =  { version = "0.4", features = ["full"] }
tonic = "*"
http = "*"
*/
use tonic::codegen::*;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Greet<Service>(Service);

impl<S> tonic::transport::NamedService for Greet<S> {
    const NAME: &'static str = "Greet";
}

impl<B, S> Service<http::Request<B>> for Greet<S>
where
    B: Body + Send + 'static,
    B::Error: Into<StdError> + Send + 'static,
{
    type Response = http::Response<tonic::body::BoxBody>;
    type Error = std::convert::Infallible;
    type Future = BoxFuture<Self::Response, Self::Error>;
    fn poll_ready(&mut self, _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
    fn call(&mut self, _req: http::Request<B>) -> Self::Future {
        // Something like 
        // self.0.call(req).await.unwrap()
        todo!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let svc = tower::service_fn(|_request: http::Response<()>| async move { todo!() });
    let greeter = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
        .load_shed()
        .concurrency_limit(3)
        .service(svc);
    tonic::transport::Server::builder().add_service(Greet(greeter));
}
```

Here is [the link to compiling code](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/wml6pz).

Hopefully you should get it working, happy `greeting`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
But your code won't compile (though it will fill in the unimported dependencies), 
the `BoxFuture` is not a `BoxFuture` from the *futures* crate, and I can't find a definition in *Tonic*.

Comment: The last piece of code compiles

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with the `NameService` trait. The following is the compiled code, but there are still semantic issues.

```rust
use futures::{future::BoxFuture, FutureExt};
use std::{
    convert::Infallible,
    marker::PhantomData,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};
use tonic::{  // tonic-0.9.2
    transport::{NamedService, Server},
    Request, Response, Status,
};
use tower::{BoxError, Service};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct NamedWrapper<S, O> {
    inner: S,
    _origin_svc_type: PhantomData<O>,
}

impl<S, O> NamedService for NamedWrapper<S, O>
where
    O: NamedService,
{
    const NAME: &'static str = O::NAME;
}

impl<S, O, Req> Service<Req> for NamedWrapper<S, O>
where
    S: Service<Req> + 'static,
    S::Response: Send + 'static,
    S::Future: Send + 'static,
    S::Error: Into<BoxError> + std::fmt::Debug + Send + 'static,
{
    type Response = S::Response;
    // Due to the input parameter of the `Server::add_service(svc)` method -
    // the association type representing the error of the `svc` must be of the `Infailable` type
    type Error = Infallible;
    type Future = BoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    fn poll_ready(&mut self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.inner.poll_ready(cx).map(|r| {
            if let Err(e) = r {
                // How to handle this error? We need this error, but the Infallible type is not allowed.
                eprintln!("{:?}", e);
            }
            Ok(())
        })
    }

    fn call(&mut self, req: Req) -> Self::Future {
        let fut = self.inner.call(req).boxed();
        Box::pin(async move {
            // It's impossible not to raise an error. In fact, the `Status` type should be returned, but it's limited by the Infailable type
            // In this example, due to the effect of `load-shed`, an `Overloaded` error will be thrown
            Ok(fut.await.unwrap())
        })
    }
}

impl<T, O> NamedWrapper<T, O>
where
    O: NamedService,
{
    pub fn new(svc: T, ost: PhantomData<O>) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: svc,
            _origin_svc_type: ost,
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "[::1]:50051".parse().unwrap();

    let greeter = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
        .load_shed()
        .concurrency_limit(3)
        .service(GreeterServer::new(MyGreeter::default()));
    let greeter = NamedWrapper::new(greeter, PhantomData::<GreeterServer<MyGreeter>>);

    let echo = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
        .load_shed()
        .concurrency_limit(2)
        .service(EchoServer::new(MyEcho::default()));
    let echo = NamedWrapper::new(echo, PhantomData::<EchoServer<MyEcho>>);

    Server::builder()
        .add_service(greeter)
        .add_service(echo)
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
// Omit the remaining code and refer to the example in Tonic: https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/src/multiplex/server.rs
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer provided?

Comment: Oh, you updated the code link and were able to compile, that's amazing! Before that, I copied your code to the *VSCode* IDE, filled in the missing dependencies, and found that the `BoxFuture` type was incorrect, so I couldn't compile it.

There is not much difference in our code, but neither of us can ultimately solve the problem: How to handle errors returned by internal specific services in the `poll_ready()` and `call()` methods?